# JavaScript Dates

Tags: javascript, function, date

How would I be able to change the code `document.write(" until the the designated date")` to the date in `writeMessage(date)`? Also, the date in `writeMessage(date)` isn't going through properly (only the year comes through).  Thank you for any help fixing this!

```js
function beginMessage(number, timeType) {
  if (number > 0) {
  document.write("There are ");
  document.write(number);
  document.write(" ");
  document.write(timeType);
  document.write(" until the designated date.");
  document.write("<br>");
} else {
  number = -number;
  document.write("There have been ");
  document.write(number);
  document.write(" ");
  document.write(timeType);
  document.write(" since the designated date.");
  document.write("<br>");
}

  if (((timeType === undefined || number === undefined || isNaN(number)))) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function writeMessage(date) {
  clearDocument();
  var today = new Date();
  var calculateDate = new Date(date);

  var milliseconds = calculateDate.getTime() - today.getTime();

  beginMessage(milliseconds, "milliseconds");

  var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
  seconds = parseInt(seconds);

  beginMessage(seconds, "seconds");

  var minutes = seconds / 60;
  minutes = parseInt(minutes);

  beginMessage(minutes, "minutes");

  var hours = minutes / 60;
  hours = parseInt(hours);

  beginMessage(hours, "hours");

  var days = hours / 24;
  days = parseInt(days);

  beginMessage(days, "days");

  var weeks = days / 7;
  weeks = parseInt(weeks);

  beginMessage(weeks, "weeks");

  if ((date === undefined || isNaN(date))) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
  }

  setTimeout("writeMessage('" + date + "');", 1);
}

function clearDocument() {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
}



writeMessage("2017-07-04");
```

Comment: You have to use something that beginMessage can read. So either a (global) variable, or another parameter in beginMessage: `beginMessage(milliseconds, "milliseconds", date);`

Comment: `document.write` is 20th century, and for this sort of output, it's probably not even close to useful

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment:

```
// 'global' variable that both beginMessage and writeMessage can access
var writtenDate = null;

function beginMessage(number, timeType) {
  if (number > 0) {
  ...
  document.write(" until " + writtenDate);
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
}

function writeMessage(date) {
  // save the date sent to this function is the variable, so beginMessage can see it as well.
  writtenDate = date;
  ...
}

function clearDocument() {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
}

writeMessage("2017-07-04");

// OR preferably: an extra parameter.

function beginMessage(number, timeType, designatedDate) {
  if (number > 0) {
  ...
  document.write(" until " + designatedDate);
  ...
} else {
  ...
}

function writeMessage(date) {
  ...
  beginMessage(milliseconds, "milliseconds", date);
  ...
  beginMessage(seconds, "seconds", date);
  ...
  beginMessage(minutes, "minutes", date);
  ...
  beginMessage(hours, "hours", date);
  ...
  beginMessage(days, "days", date);
  ...
  beginMessage(weeks, "weeks", date);
  ...
}

...

writeMessage("2017-07-04");
```

Answer (score 0):

Shilly has most of the answer. Regarding:

> only the year comes through

When you call *document.write* after the page has finished loading, it first clears the **entire** document, including the script that called it. So at some point the document finishes loading and you erase the script so it can't run any more. You see whatever is written to the page at that point.

So:

1. Don't use *document.write*, show your output some other way (e.g *element.textContent*)
2. If you must use it, construct a single string and use a single *document.write* while the page is loading
3. Don't call it after the page has loaded unless you want to clear the entire document

Lastly, your date arithmetic is broken. `new Date("2017-07-04")` will parse the string as UTC, so the time difference will be adjusted by the timezone offset of the host system. Fine if it's set to UTC+0000, but not otherwise.